# how to calculate total working hours for all users?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a code that takes two arrays :

**Login array**

**Logout Array**

and then my code finds difference between one login and logout, so that would be his working duration in office. So will calculate all the duration and will get total worked hours for a single user for each date. of month.

Now this does for only one user . How can i calculate every user's total duration  and print it in view?

```
<?php
                $loginarry = $attendances_logins;
                $logoutarry =$attendances_logouts;
                $timeduration=0;
                $login_i=0;
                $logout_i=0;


                echo '<table border="1px"  class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-example">';
                echo '<tr><th>Login</th><th>Logout</th><th>Duration</th></tr>';

                //echo ("Array Length = " . count($loginarry)." & ".count($logoutarry)."\n<br/>");
        while(true)
        { 
            if( $login_i >= count($loginarry) && $logout_i >= count($logoutarry))
                break;

            if( $logout_i >= count($logoutarry))
            {
                //echo ("Login[".$login_i."] : ".$loginarry[$login_i]->date_data." and Logout : -----------------\n<br/>");


echo ("<tr><td>".$loginarry[$login_i]->date_data." </td><td>Not Available</td><td>Not Available</td></tr>");


    //          echo ("<tr> <td>".$loginarry->date_data." </td><td> Data Not Available</td></tr>");
                $login_i++;
                continue;
            }

            if(($login_i+1) == count($loginarry) && ($logout_i+1) < count($logoutarry))
            {
                echo ("<tr><td>Data Not Available </td><td>".$logoutarry[$logout_i]->date_data."\n</td><td>Data Not Available</td></tr>");
            $logout_i++;
            continue;
            }

            if( $login_i >= count($loginarry))
            {
                echo ("<tr><td> Data Not Available </td><td>".$logoutarry[$logout_i]->date_data."\n<td>Data Not Available</td></td></tr>");
                            $logout_i++;
                continue;
            }
            //echo( "******* ".(new DateTime($loginarry[$login_i+1]->date_data))->format('U') . " **** ".(new DateTime($logoutarry[$logout_i]->date_data))->format('U'). "\n<br/>");

            //check if next login time is smaller then current logout time - if so skip current login time
            if($login_i < (count($loginarry)-1) && (new DateTime($logoutarry[$logout_i]->date_data))->format('U') > (new DateTime($loginarry[$login_i+1]->date_data))->format('U'))
            //if( date_diff(date_create($logoutarry[$logout_i]->date_data), date_create($loginarry[$login_i+1]->date_data)) > 0 )
            {
                echo ("<tr><td>".$loginarry[$login_i]->date_data."</td><td>Data Not Available</td><td>Data Not Available</td></tr>");
                $login_i++;
                continue;
            }

           //
            if( (new DateTime($loginarry[$login_i]->date_data))->format('U') > (new DateTime($logoutarry[$logout_i]->date_data))->format('U') )
            //if( date_diff(date_create($loginarry[$login_i]->date_data), date_create($logoutarry[$logout_i]->date_data)) > 0 )
                    {
                echo ("<tr><td>Data Not Available </td><td>".$logoutarry[$logout_i]->date_data."\n</td><td>Data Not Available</td></tr>");

                            $logout_i++;
                            continue;
                    }

            //if more logout entries then skip to last logout entry
            if( $login_i < (count($loginarry)-1) && $logout_i < (count($logoutarry)-1) && (new DateTime($logoutarry[$logout_i+1]->date_data))->format('U') < (new DateTime($loginarry[$login_i+1]->date_data))->format('U'))
            {
                echo(" <tr><td> Data Not Available</td> <td>".$logoutarry[$logout_i]->date_data."\n</td> <td>Data Not Available</td> </tr>");
                            $logout_i++;
                            continue;
            }

            echo ("<tr><td> ".$loginarry[$login_i]->date_data."</td>  <td>".$logoutarry[$logout_i]->date_data."</td>");




            $singleduration = ((new DateTime($logoutarry[$logout_i]->date_data))->format('U') - (new DateTime($loginarry[$login_i]->date_data))->format('U'));
            if($singleduration > 43200)//12 hours X 3600 seconds)
            {   
                 //$timeduration += $singleduration;
                 echo ("<td class='danger'>Huge duration - not considered - please contact HR (".$singleduration.")</td></tr>");
            }
            else
            {
                 $timeduration += $singleduration;
                 echo ("<td>".gmdate("H:i:s",$singleduration)."</td></tr>");
            }
            $login_i++;
            $logout_i++;

        }

            echo ("</table>");

            //$finaltime=gmdate("H:i:s",$timeduration);
            //$timedurationstr = ConvertSecondsToStr($timeduration);
            $hours = 0;
            if($timeduration > 3600)
            {
                $hours = floor($timeduration/3600);
                $timeduration -= (3600*$hours);
            }
            $min = 0;
            if($timeduration > 60)
            {
                $min = floor($timeduration/60);
                $timeduration -= (60*$min);
            }
            $seconds = $timeduration;



           //echo("<div class= 'row'> <div class ='col-sm-4' style= 'float:right'><h3 class='alert alert-success'><center>Total Hours Worked ". $finaltime." Hours</center></h3></div></div>");
           echo("<div class= 'row'> <div class ='col-sm-4' style= 'float:right'><h3 class='alert alert-success'><center>Total time worked: ". $hours." Hour(s) ".$min." Minute(s) ".$seconds." Second(s)</center></h3></div></div>");
           //echo("<div class= 'row'> <div class ='col-sm-4' style= 'float:right'><h3 class='alert alert-success'><center>Total time worked: ". $timedurationstr." </center></h3></div></div>");

                ?>
```

the Model code:

```
 public function all_login($emp_id)
{

    $startDate = new DateTime("first day of last month");
    $endDate = new DateTime("last day of last month");
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('daily_data2');
    $this->db->where('users.emp_id',$emp_id);
    $this->db->where('entry >','100');
    $this->db->where("date(date_data) BETWEEN '" . $startDate->format( 'Y-m-d' ) . "' AND '" . $endDate->format( 'Y-m-d') . "' ");                                                  
    $this->db->order_by("date_data","ASC");
    $this->db->join('users', 'users.emp_id = daily_data2.emp_id','inner');     
    $query = $this->db->get(); 
    $res   = $query->result();        
    return $res;

}




public function all_logout($emp_id)
{


      $startDate = new DateTime("first day of last month");
      $endDate = new DateTime("last day of last month");
      $this->db->select('*');
      $this->db->from('daily_data2');
      $this->db->where('users.emp_id',$emp_id);
      $this->db->where('entry <','100');
      $this->db->where("date(date_data) BETWEEN '" . $startDate->format( 'Y-m-d' ) . "' AND '" . $endDate->format( 'Y-m-d') . "' ");                                                     
      $this->db->order_by("date_data","ASC");
      $this->db->join('users', 'users.emp_id = daily_data2.emp_id','inner');
      $query = $this->db->get(); 
      $res   = $query->result();        
      return $res;


}
```

The Arrays:

```
          array (size=21)
        0 => 
          object(stdClass)[27]
            public 'id' => string '1' (length=1)
            public 'emp_id' => string '1' (length=1)
            public 'name' => string 'Hiren' (length=5)
            public 'last_name' => string 'Gada' (length=4)
            public 'user_type' => string 'employee' (length=8)
            public 'email' => string 'hiren@bizrtc.com' (length=16)
            public 'password' => string '55f32a0322e3b2f1bf8f41e20bd1dd075f50cfc2becc4fd9bc85ac10eea4bf0c5be3b00596f1d8b4fda6e5ab1c3c388bc28fdc0454bc260382be86613057f045' (length=128)
            public 'phone' => string '9999999999' (length=10)
            public 'gender' => string 'Male' (length=4)
            public 'designation' => string 'CEO' (length=3)
            public 'blood_group' => string '+ve' (length=3)
            public 'date_birth' => string 'DD-MM-YYYY' (length=10)
            public 'status' => string 'active' (length=6)
            public 'address' => string 'DD-MM-YYYY' (length=10)
        1 => 




    object(stdClass)[310]
            public 'id' => string '2' (length=1)
            public 'emp_id' => string '3' (length=1)
            public 'date_data' => string '2015-12-01 18:20:15' (length=19)
            public 'abc' => string '1' (length=1)
            public 'def' => string '0' (length=1)
            public 'entry' => string '101' (length=3)
            public 'ghi' => string '0' (length=1)
            public 'status' => string 'active' (length=6)
            public 'name' => string 'Deepa' (length=5)
            public 'last_name' => string 'Gada' (length=4)
            public 'user_type' => string 'employee' (length=8)
            public 'email' => string 'deepa@bizrtc.com' (length=16)
            public 'password' => string '108fae131090e2cd93d569050a105f5187a3a9c2e9fef0010f4acea30d999834d4c36cd0435550a42b8c98f9a7dcbfd05cb9b1428aa596a71b44e20879e233bb' (length=128)
            public 'phone' => string '9999999999' (length=10)
            public 'gender' => string 'Female' (length=6)
            public 'designation' => string 'Sr. Software' (length=12)
            public 'blood_group' => string '+ve' (length=3)
            public 'date_birth' => string 'DD-MM-YYYY' (length=10)
            public 'address' => string 'DD-MM-YYYY' (length=10)




              object(stdClass)[1142]
            public 'id' => string '20' (length=2)
            public 'emp_id' => string '22' (length=2)
            public 'date_data' => string '2015-12-11 07:34:22' (length=19)
            public 'abc' => string '1' (length=1)
            public 'def' => string '0' (length=1)
            public 'entry' => string '101' (length=3)
            public 'ghi' => string '0' (length=1)
            public 'status' => string 'active' (length=6)
            public 'name' => string 'Parveen' (length=7)
            public 'last_name' => string 'Thakur' (length=6)
            public 'user_type' => string 'employee' (length=8)
            public 'email' => string 'praveen@bizrtc.com' (length=18)
            public 'password' => string '3eee66dbace42d2e671c52013e41de441b176dbaa0f7df33a5811b86c78b60ecb5328184bf1f5057f94817801140d7287f31c1fb06fa65550c356a33a8eec0db' (length=128)
            public 'phone' => string '9999999999' (length=10)
            public 'gender' => string 'Male' (length=4)
            public 'designation' => string 'Support Staff' (length=13)
            public 'blood_group' => string '+ve' (length=3)
            public 'date_birth' => string 'DD-MM-YYYY' (length=10)
            public 'address' => string 'DD-MM-YYYY' (length=10)
```

Comment: You perhaps should add the arrays in question ( or at the least an example of them )

Comment: create two fields, starthour, endhour, update start hour field at the time of login, (store datetime) and at the time of logout store datetime aswell, and than calculate.. suggestion...

Comment: i think you want to insert and update every single user working hour in your database one field and update every time as per working hours so its stored working hours for all user and you will sum it using sql query and get total working hours for all users

Comment: @devpro thanks for u suggestion will surely try that

Comment: @RamRaider adding the three array in question check it

Comment: i mean you want to store every total hours in users table one column and sum all users total our  when you need total time of all users

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this

```
foreach ($users as $user) 
{ 
    $emp_id = $user['emp_id']; 
    $name = $user['name'];
    $attendances_logins = $this->attendance_m->all_login($emp_id); 
    $attendances_logouts = $this->attendance_m->all_logout($emp_id); 

    foreach ($attendances_logins as $key => $value) {
        $loginTime = $value['login_time'];
        $logoutTime = $attendances_logouts[$key]['logout_time']''

    }

    $login_logout[] = array(
        'emp_id' => $emp_id,
        'name' =>$name,
        'hours' =>$hours,
        'min' => $min,
        'seconds' =>$seconds,
        'login' => $attendances_logins, # Count number only 
        'logout' => $attendances_logouts # Count number only 
    );
}
$this->data['logins'] = $login_logout
// load view
```